# Extract the string from the document using regex in python

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract a string from a document with the following regex pattern in python.
string will always start with either "AK" or "BK"..followed by numbers or letters or - or /(any order)
This string pattern can contain anywhere in the document

```
document_text="""
This is the organization..this is the address. 
AKBN
some information
AK3418CPMP
lot of other information down
BKCPU
"""
```

I have written following code.

```
pattern="(?:AK|BK)[A-Za-z0-9-/]+"
res_list=re.findall(pattern,document_text)
```

but I am getting the list contains AKs and BKs
something like this

```
res_list=['AKBN','BKCPU','AK3418CPMP']
```

when I just use

```
res_grp=re.search(pattern,document_text)
res=res_grp.group(1)
```

I just get `'AKBN'`

it is also matching the words "AKBN", "BKCPU"
along with the required "AK3418CPMP" when I use `findall`.
I want conditions to be following to extract only 1 string "AK3418CPMP":

1. string should start with AK or BK
2. It should followed by letters and numbers or numbers and letters
3. It can contain "-" or "/"

How can I only extract "AK3418CPMP"

Comment: use python logic after you parsed the regex to filter out the strings that don't have both numbers and letters

Comment: This might work for you. `(AK|BK)([A-Za-z-/]+[0-9]+)|([0-9]+[A-Za-z-/]+)`, [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/UM55ba/1/), it only looks for a cooherent sting og letter, and numbers, but not AK-numbers-letters-numbers, that would fail, is that required?

Comment: ```r'\b[AK|BK]\w[A-Za-z]+[\d@]+[\w@]*|[\d@]+[A-Za-z]+[\w@]*'```?

Comment: *"It should be followed by letters and numbers or numbers and letters"* Please clarify what you mean by that by giving some examples. Do the dashes and slashes `-` and `/`  count as numbers or letters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make sure to match at least a single digit after matching AK or BK and move the `-` to the end of the character class or else it would denote a range.

```
\b[AB]K[A-Za-z/-]*[0-9][A-Za-z0-9/-]*
```

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial match
- `[AB]K` Match either AK or BK
- `[A-Za-z/-]*` Optionally repeat matching chars A-Za-z `/` or `-` without a digit
- `[0-9]` Match at least a single digit
- `[A-Za-z0-9/-]*` Optionally match what is listed in the character class including the digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mofAqI/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your regex, and make python do the filtering.

```py
 import re                                                                  
                                                                            
 document_text="""    
 This is the organization..this is the address.    
 AKBN    
 some information    
 AK3418CPMP    
 lot of other information down    
 BKCPU    
 """    
     
 pattern="(?:AK|BK)[A-Za-z0-9-/]+"    
 res_list=[x for x in    
         re.findall(pattern,document_text)    
         if re.search(r'\d', x)    
         and re.search(r'\w', x)]    
     
 print(res_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can include a 'match at least' clause like: `([AB]K[A-Z]{1,}[0-9]{1,})|([AB]K[0-9]{1,}[A-Z]{1,})`. This would cover your 1st and 2nd needs. You can customize this regex condition to track the '-' and '/' cases too.

Let's suppose you would like to track cases where the '-' or '/' would separate your substrings :

```
([AB]K(-|\/){0,1}[A-Z]{1,}(-|\/){0,1}[0-9]{1,})|([AB]K(-|\/){0,1}[0-9]{1,}(-|\/){0,1}[A-Z]{1,})
```